# How to prevent displaying window on application startup osx

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am learning Objective-C and programming applications for OS X. I want to write myself a simple notifier, which should work this way:

- connect to website and check, if there is new content (I have that covered)
- display window with action buttons like "ignore", "visit website" (this is also easy)

I thought, that I will add my app to startup and if there are no changes on the website - just terminate it. But the window with action buttons will pop up before application checks, if there is a new content and window will flash quickly. How do I prevent that?

Is there a better way to create something like this? For example instead of running my application during startup - running a daemon, that will check the website every 24 hours and then display the window? How can I do that?

Recently, I read [Start Developing Mac Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/chapters/01_Introduction.html), so I might be still missing something obvious.

Comment: Remove the window from `MainMenu.xib` and create it programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select NSWindow and just turn off Visible At Launch.

If you want to show the window, do it manually as follows.

```
- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    /* Do whatever necessary before the window appears */
    [window setIsVisible:YES];
}
```

Personally, I never have the Visible-At-Launch switch on.

[image]