# How to prevent the app from automatically open a window when launched?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am developing a OS X app and want it to run without dock icon but with a icon in the menubar. I have added the menubar utility and tried to set the following code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

```
[NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory];
```

It works well, except that the app will still show the window when launched. How to prevent this? I can't set the `LSUIElement` in `Info.plist` because I want this behavior to be changeable in the runtime.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

It seems that the `Visible At Launch` is unchecked by default... I am using storyboard so I created a new project, choose `Main.storyboard` -> Window Controller Scene -> Window, and found it unchecked, but the window will still open automatically.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yAQJ.png) (cannot post it directly with <10 reputation)

Comment: You probably have a window in your MainMenu NIB whose Visible at Launch property is turned on.

Comment: See the following post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379247/how-to-prevent-displaying-window-on-application-startup-osx/26379552#26379552

Comment: @KenThomases Thanks for your reply, but seems that it's unchecked by default... maybe i'm missing something?

Comment: @ElTomato Thanks for the link, but it does not work for me.. please check my update.